# How to change the syntax highlighting style in Meld

Tags: syntax-highlighting, meld

Meld 1.5.1 uses gtksourceview (via pygtksourceview) for its syntax-highlighting, however I'm unable to figure out how to configure it to use a specific style (color scheme/theme) from the ones available to gtksourceview.

Maybe the solution is outside of meld - eg, settings the default style used for gtksourceview in general, or something similar.

Answer (score 7):

According to the now relevant [page](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Meld/DarkThemes) :

> Update example for GTK+ 3.
>   In December 2013, Meld was updated to use GtkCssProvider instead of gtkrc (commit log).
>   The new location of its default colour profile is
>   /usr/share/meld/meld.css

There is also an example of the new way to configure meld.

Comment: Not working on Meld 3.14.2  under Ubuntu-Mate 16.04.3 LTS.
(trying to get dark colors for a general dark theme...)

Comment: OSX instructions: the style files are located in `Applications > Meld.app > Contents > Resources > share > gtksourceview-3.0 > styles`. (If not, right-click on `Meld.app`, choose "Show Package Contents", and then search for a file named `meld-base.xml` within `Meld.app`.) Duplicate your favorite style file, such as `meld-base.xml`, and edit it. In addition to modifying the hex color codes, make sure to change `id` and `_name` in `<style-scheme...>` to avoid conflict.  Restart Meld, then choose your new scheme from the drop-down menu at `Meld>Preference>Editor>Syntax Highlighting Color Scheme`.

Comment: Confirmed the OSX instructions above work; it's now 2023, and the Meld path is `/Applications/Meld.app/Contents/Resources/share/gtksourceview-4/styles`.  If you search for "gtksourceview color schemes" you'll get lots of hits -- e.g., I copied the Monokai one from https://github.com/trusktr/gedit-color-schemes/blob/master/gtksourceview-3.0/styles/Monokai.xml and dropped it in (renaming it to lowercase `monokai.xml` for consistency) and it worked.

Comment: (cont.) I also tried the Monokai Extended from https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GtkSourceView/StyleSchemes and that worked, too.  The readme at https://github.com/kberns/gtksourceview-styles lists a bunch of apps that use gtksourceview, so you can probably search for color schemes for them by name, too.  Let the colorizing begin!

Answer (score 6):

In Meld 3.16.4 you can simply choose color scheme in `Meld > Preferences`:

[image: meld prefernces]

(possibly this change was introduced in earlier versions)

Answer (score 1):

The process seems to involve creating a file ~/.gtkrc-2.0 to overwrite the [meld defaults](https://git.gnome.org/browse/meld/tree/data/gtkrc).

You can find some examples for Dark Themes in the [wiki](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Meld/DarkThemes)

Also, do not forget to change the theme name from the predefined one, or it will use that.

Answer (score 1):

I had trouble doing this in .gtkrc-2.0 for meld-1.3.0 under Solaris

Instead I found I could affect them in **~/.meld/meldrc.ini**

Example, under the [DEFAULT] section

```
color_delete_bg = #003300
color_delete_fg = red
color_replace_bg = #112233
color_replace_fg = gray80
color_conflict_bg = pink
color_conflict_fg = white
color_inline_bg = #223344
color_inline_fg = white
color_edited_bg = gray20
color_edited_fg = white
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, if it is possible to make meld to use another theme, but you always can edit default theme, which is classic.xml.

For Ubuntu 14.04 it is located in:

```
/usr/share/gtksourceview-2.0/styles/classic.xml
```

If you are using another os, location could differ.

See https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GtkSourceView/StyleSchemes.